# Refreshing data when deleting record doesn't delete item in ListView

Tags: rest, refresh, sproutcore

I started with Sproutcore recently, I created Todo app from the guides, changed datastore so that it uses RESTful webservice written in Node.js + Express.js and I added refresh button. I want to know how to refresh data properly, because when I open the page in two separate windows and delete record from one window, the item doesn't disappear after clicking refresh. When the items are created or updated, refresh works ok. 
When I click on refresh, I do following:

```
TodosThree.store.find(TodosThree.TODO_QUERY).refresh();
```

What am I missing here?